# Datetime VS Timestamp

Tags: mysql

Скажите в чем разница между `datetime` и `timestamp`  хотя каждый из них сохраняет точно так же.

Comment: `datetime` - это текущее время дата и т.д. `timestamp` - это отпечаток времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DATETIME

Хранит время в виде целого числа вида *YYYYMMDDHHMMSS*, используя для этого 8 байтов. Это время не зависит от временной зоны. Оно всегда отображается при выборке точно так же, как было сохранено, независимо от того какой часовой пояс установлен в MySQL.

### TIMESTAMP

Хранит 4-байтное целое число, равное количеству секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года по усреднённому времени Гринвича (т.е. нулевой часовой пояс, точка отсчёта часовых поясов). При получении из базы отображается с учётом часового пояса. Часовой пояс может быть задан в операционной системе, глобальных настройках MySQL или в конкретной сессии. Запомните, что сохраняется всегда количество секунд по UTC (универсальное координированное время, солнечное время на меридиане Гринвича), а не по локальному часовому поясу.

[Источник](https://habr.com/post/61391/)